# Update viewport state after fitBounds is called

Tags: react-map-gl

I have created a map using react-map-gl.  Whenever I zoom or pan on the map, the viewport updates as the `onViewStateChange` prop calls an _updateViewPort function which sets the new state.  The issue I am having is, when I zoom into somewhere using the mapbox function `fitBounds` the onViewStateChange does not seem to fire, and as a result the viewport state never changes.  As a result, next time I pan or zoom on the map, it takes me back to where I was before I called the `fitBounds` method.  Has anyone experienced this before, and have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

What ended up working is calculating the new latitude, longitude, and zoom for my new extent I was zooming to using `WebMercatorViewport`, and then set that as the new viewport state. I used the `FlyToInterpolator` method that react-map-gl offers to fly to that location.

```
const {longitude, latitude, zoom } = new WebMercatorViewport(this.state.viewport)
.fitBounds([[extent[0], extent[1]], [extent[2], extent[3]]], {padding: {top: 82, bottom: 30, left: leftPadding, right: 30}});
const viewport = {
  ...this.state.viewport,
  longitude,
  latitude,
  zoom,
  transitionDuration: 2000,
  transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator()
}
this.setState({viewport});
```

Comment: This is the best I can find. Here, what you mean by the "extent" is actually a "bounds" with `[min, max, min, max]` values.